# Racket Pass List Elements to a Macro

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to pass the values that I have within a list to a macro.

Ex:

```
(define l (list (list 1) (list 2) (list 3 4))) --> l = '((1) (2) (3 4))
(define-syntax myMacro
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(myMacro <expr> ...) (printf "~a\n" <expr> ...)]))
```

How would I got about doing this? Since if you try to use `(apply myMacro l)` you get a bad syntax in: myMacro warning. How would I be able to do this?

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile-time, when no values exist, and you can't `apply` them. Use a function.

Comment: How would I go about using a function moldnilo

Comment: `(define (f . args) (apply printf "~a\n" args))`. That’s not very useful, since the format string expects one argument, but it mirrors what your macro is doing. Perhaps you want to use the `~a` function from `racket/format`?